# Set Required = false in virtual property, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and I am using Entity framework.
I have a model named Propiedad and this have some virtual properties without Required attibute, in the view I have a dropdown for the virtual properties and when I do not select an option this tell me that I have to select an option.

I need that Grupo property does not need to select another option, that I can select the optionLabel without show me validator error message.

This is the model:

```
public class Propiedad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Entidad Entidad { get; set; }
    public virtual PestanasPorEntidad Pestana { get; set; }
    public virtual GrupoDePropiedades Grupo { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string TipoDeDatos { get; set; }
    public bool Requerido { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Orden { get; set; }
    public string Columna { get; set; }
}
```

This is part of the view (Create):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Grupo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Grupo.Id, (SelectList)(ViewBag.PestanaList), "Ninguno", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Grupo)
    </div>
</div>
```

This is part of the controller

```
private void SetGrupoListViewBag()
    {
        ViewBag.GrupoList = new SelectList(unitOfWork.GrupoDePropiedadesRepository.Get(), "id", "nombre");
    }

// GET: /GlobalAdmin/Propiedades/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var propiedad = new Propiedad();
    SetTipoDeDatosListViewBag();
    SetEntidadListViewBag();
    SetPestanaListViewBag();
    SetColumnaListViewBag();
    SetGrupoListViewBag();
    var entidadId = Request["entidadId"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request["entidadId"]) : -1;
    if (entidadId != -1)
    {
        propiedad.Entidad = unitOfWork.EntidadRepository.GetById(entidadId);
        return View(propiedad);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: basically you need that the dropdown field is not required, what about if you use ? in front of it?

Comment: @EstebanV this doesn't work

Comment: Your dropdownlist is binding to property `Grupo.Id` which presumably is typeof `int` which must always have a value (`int` cannot be `null`). Your property would need to be `int?` (nullable) or better, use a view model